# Resize images in PHP at a specific size

Tags: php, image, resize

Have this piece of code allowing me to charge an image on my webserver.
These two script works but not together. The first on is to charge the image on my server and the second one is to resize my image. I try out some post on SO but I can't find the right way to make it works with my original code.

```
<?php
    $fileName = $_FILES['AddPhoto']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['AddPhoto']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['AddPhoto']['size']/1024;
    $fileType = $_FILES['AddPhoto']['type'];
    $fileExtension = end(explode(".", $fileName));

    if(($fileType == "image/gif" || $fileType == "image/jpeg" || $fileType == "image/pjpeg" || $fileType == "image/png" || $fileType == "image/x-png") && $fileSize < 1000000) {

        $newFileName = md5(date('u').rand(0,99)).".".$fileExtension;
        $imagePath = "assets/picts/".$newFileName;

        $result = @move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $imagePath);

        $request = mysql_query("SELECT ".$TypeField."Images FROM $TypeFiche WHERE $TypeId='$cardId'");
        $var2 = mysql_fetch_array($request);

        mysql_query("UPDATE ".$TypeFiche." SET `".$TypeField."Images`='".$var2[$TypeField.'Images'].$newFileName.",' WHERE $TypeId='$cardId'");

        if (!$result) {
            $newImgMessError = "Error.<br />";
        }
        if ($result) {
            $newImgMessError = "Valid.<br />";
        }
    }
?>
```

I want to have the possibility to resize the image.

Any clue and help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$_FILES['AddPhoto'] is your image file, transfered to server. You save it in $imagepath. This path is what you need when you create JPEG image (for others are different functions) with function like imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath). From this point on you can use a lot of examples that you have found in StackOverflow. One was already published by Juan David Decano in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple class

```
<?php
/**
 * Resize image class will allow you to resize an image
 *
 * Can resize to exact size
 * Max width size while keep aspect ratio
 * Max height size while keep aspect ratio
 * Automatic while keep aspect ratio
 */
class ResizeImage
{
    private $ext;
    private $image;
    private $newImage;
    private $origWidth;
    private $origHeight;
    private $resizeWidth;
    private $resizeHeight;

    /**
     * Class constructor requires to send through the image filename
     *
     * @param string $filename - Filename of the image you want to resize
     */
    public function __construct( $filename )
    {
        if(file_exists($filename))
        {
            $this->setImage( $filename );
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Image ' . $filename . ' can not be found, try another image.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the image variable by using image create
     *
     * @param string $filename - The image filename
     */
    private function setImage( $filename )
    {
        $size = getimagesize($filename);
        $this->ext = $size['mime'];

        switch($this->ext)
        {
            // Image is a JPG
            case 'image/jpg':
            case 'image/jpeg':
                // create a jpeg extension
                $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
                break;

            // Image is a GIF
            case 'image/gif':
                $this->image = @imagecreatefromgif($filename);
                break;

            // Image is a PNG
            case 'image/png':
                $this->image = @imagecreatefrompng($filename);
                break;

            // Mime type not found
            default:
                throw new Exception("File is not an image, please use another file type.", 1);
        }

        $this->origWidth = imagesx($this->image);
        $this->origHeight = imagesy($this->image);
    }

    /**
     * Save the image as the image type the original image was
     *
     * @param  String[type] $savePath     - The path to store the new image
     * @param  string $imageQuality       - The qulaity level of image to create
     *
     * @return Saves the image
     */
    public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100", $download = false)
    {
        switch($this->ext)
        {
            case 'image/jpg':
            case 'image/jpeg':
                // Check PHP supports this file type
                if (imagetypes() &#038; IMG_JPG) {
                    imagejpeg($this->newImage, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                }
                break;

            case 'image/gif':
                // Check PHP supports this file type
                if (imagetypes() &#038; IMG_GIF) {
                    imagegif($this->newImage, $savePath);
                }
                break;

            case 'image/png':
                $invertScaleQuality = 9 - round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                // Check PHP supports this file type
                if (imagetypes() &#038; IMG_PNG) {
                    imagepng($this->newImage, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                }
                break;
        }

        if($download)
        {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ".$savePath."");
            readfile($savePath);
        }

        imagedestroy($this->newImage);
    }

    /**
     * Resize the image to these set dimensions
     *
     * @param  int $width           - Max width of the image
     * @param  int $height          - Max height of the image
     * @param  string $resizeOption - Scale option for the image
     *
     * @return Save new image
     */
    public function resizeTo( $width, $height, $resizeOption = 'default' )
    {
        switch(strtolower($resizeOption))
        {
            case 'exact':
                $this->resizeWidth = $width;
                $this->resizeHeight = $height;
            break;

            case 'maxwidth':
                $this->resizeWidth  = $width;
                $this->resizeHeight = $this->resizeHeightByWidth($width);
            break;

            case 'maxheight':
                $this->resizeWidth  = $this->resizeWidthByHeight($height);
                $this->resizeHeight = $height;
            break;

            default:
                if($this->origWidth > $width || $this->origHeight > $height)
                {
                    if ( $this->origWidth > $this->origHeight ) {
                         $this->resizeHeight = $this->resizeHeightByWidth($width);
                         $this->resizeWidth  = $width;
                    } else if( $this->origWidth < $this->origHeight ) {
                        $this->resizeWidth  = $this->resizeWidthByHeight($height);
                        $this->resizeHeight = $height;
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->resizeWidth = $width;
                    $this->resizeHeight = $height;
                }
            break;
        }

        $this->newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($this->resizeWidth, $this->resizeHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($this->newImage, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->resizeWidth, $this->resizeHeight, $this->origWidth, $this->origHeight);
    }

    /**
     * Get the resized height from the width keeping the aspect ratio
     *
     * @param  int $width - Max image width
     *
     * @return Height keeping aspect ratio
     */
    private function resizeHeightByWidth($width)
    {
        return floor(($this->origHeight/$this->origWidth)*$width);
    }

    /**
     * Get the resized width from the height keeping the aspect ratio
     *
     * @param  int $height - Max image height
     *
     * @return Width keeping aspect ratio
     */
    private function resizeWidthByHeight($height)
    {
        return floor(($this->origWidth/$this->origHeight)*$height);
    }
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
$resize = new ResizeImage('images/Be-Original.jpg');
$resize->resizeTo(100, 100, 'maxWidth');
$resize->saveImage('images/be-original-maxWidth.jpg');
```

Resource and more examples:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/resize-image-class-php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}
echo $scr;
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
$newwidth=60;
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
$newwidth1=25;
$newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);
$filename = "images/". $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filename1 = "images/small". $_FILES['file']['name'];
imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
```